# box-shadow: inset doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, css

I've been attempting to use `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9);` on an input field and it doesn't seem to work on iOS.
Is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this should help your problem.
It seems the main thing, is that you have your blur radius(3rd pixel value) set to 0px.
A known problem with box-shadow and older versions of safari is just that, if you have your blur raduis set to 0px, it won't work.

I hope this helps your problem.

"""Safari 6, iOS 6 and Android 2.3 default browser don't work with a 0px value for "blur-radius".

e.g. -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 1px 0px 1px #f04e29; 
doesn't work, but

-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 1px 1px 1px #f04e29 
does."""

This info was found at http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Comment: Although technically that does solve the problem in terms of it works. It adds a blur which is not what I am after...